# How to get the name of the grandparent directory?

Tags: bash, shell

If I have the path `one/two/three/four/here.md` the name I should get is `three`.

If I have path `a/b/filename.md` the name should I get is `a`.

The path looks like `./topic/sub/guides`.

EDIT:

To clear my intention, I want the "three" for example in a variable inside a bash script.

Comment: Do you want path resolution?  ie, if the path is `one/two/../../one/here.md`, what result do you want?

Comment: To clear my intention, I want the "three" for example in a variable inside a bash script. @WilliamPursell

Comment: For the path `one/two/../three/filename.md` to you want `..` (as produced by KamilCuk's solution) or `one` (as produced by Ted Lyngmo's solution)?

Comment: Do you want symlinks resolved?  For instance, if you run `mkdir -p a/b/c/d; touch a/b/c/d/e.f; ln -s c a/b/clink`, what do you want to get for the path `a/b/clink/d/e.f`?  Do you want `clink` (as produced by KamilCuk's solution) or `c` (as produced by Ted Lyngmo's solution)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's two dirs up and the base of a name.

```
var=a/b/filename.md
basename "$(dirname "$(dirname "$var")")"
```

Comment: Fails with `var=-one/-two/-three/four/here.md`.

Comment: This may have unwanted results when soft links are involved. Insofar the OPs question seems a bit underspecified.

Comment: @KamilCuk change it to `basename -- "$(dirname -- "$(dirname -- "$var")")"`

Comment: @InnocentBystander, that's much better, but it still fails on some exotic paths.  E.g. `var=$'a/b/\n/here.md'`.  See [dirname and basename vs parameter expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253524/264812).  Writing shell code that can properly handle all valid paths is outrageously difficult.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use `realpath` and then `basename`:

```
the_dir='./topic/sub/guides'
basename -- "$(realpath -m -- "$the_dir/../..")"
```